# Python- Mocking API request?

Tags: python, api

What am I doing wrong? I have an extractor that works great but writing the test is stumping me and it's failing. Can anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
 
 import pandas as pd
 import requests
 from my_project.task import extractor
 from my_project.tests import utils
 from prefect.logging import disable_run_logger
 
 CONTACT_RECORD = utils.TEST_CONTACT_RECORD
 PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD = utils.TEST_PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD
 EXPECTED_CONTACT_RECORD = utils.EXPECTED_CONTACT_RECORD


 @patch("requests.get")
 def test_contact_extractor(get: MagicMock):
     """
     Should call "request.get" once and return a json
     containing contact data.
     """
 
     get.return_value.json.return_value = CONTACT_RECORD
 
     with disable_run_logger():
         result = extractor.get_contacts()
         assert get.call_count == 1
         assert result == pd.DataFrame(EXPECTED_CONTACT_RECORD)
 
 
 @patch("my_project.extractor.get_contacts")
 def test_get_paged_contacts(get_contacts: MagicMock):
     """
     Should run "requests.get" until ['has-more'] is False
     and there is no offset value.
     """
     get_contacts.return_value.json.side_effect = [
         PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
         PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
         PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
         CONTACT_RECORD,
     ]
     with disable_run_logger():
         data = extractor.get_paged_contacts(
             endpoint=MagicMock, query_string=MagicMock, df=MagicMock
         )
     assert get_contacts.call_count == 4
     assert data == pd.DataFrame(EXPECTED_CONTACT_RECORD)
```

Some errors I'm getting are:

- requests imported but not used
- callable[[Union[str,btyes],....], Response] has no attribute "return_value"

EDIT:
No longer getting the second error because I realized I had a typo, but currently getting:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Edit:

Here is my get_paged_data() function:

```
 def get_paged_contacts(
     endpoint: str, query_string: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any], df: pd.DataFrame
 ) -> pd.DataFrame:
     """
     Return the results of the get request.
 
     Loops over api response and appends the results of a while loop for pagination, then
     merges the results with the previously extracted dataframe.
     """
     url = endpoint
     contacts = []
     response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=header, params=query_string).json()
     has_more = response["has-more"]
     offset = response["vid-offset"]
 
     while has_more is True:
         querystring = {"limit": "100", "archived": "false", "offset": offset}
         try:
             response = requests.request(
                 "GET", url, headers=header, params=querystring
             ).json()
             time.sleep(10)
         except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError) as j:
             logger.error(f"Error occurred: {j}.")
             break
     for x in range(len(response["contacts"])):
         contacts.append(response["contacts"][x])
 
     contacts = json_normalize(contacts)
     merged = pd.concat([df, contacts])
     return merged
```

Comment: The first "error" seems normal, you are not using requests, you are patching the get function of the module. You do not have to import the module to patch a function in it. Where is the second error thrown, in the first or the second test?

Comment: Oh understood about the imports! I was getting it on the second test, but I realized I had get_contacts.return_value.json.side_effect.return_value initially. Now I'm getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'client'

Comment: Thanks for the update. The error you are getting means that you do something.client where this something is None. I guess this is inside the get_paged_contacts function, but the code is not available to investigate more. Probably it has to do with the function arguments that you pass to the function, do you really want to pass MagicMock for endpoint, query_string and df if you already mock the get_contacts function that performs the request?

Comment: That's exactly what's stumping me because I have arguments in the function so I'm not sure how I go about calling it correctly. I've edited to add the get_paged_contacts function above

Comment: You are mocking the wrong name. Either `myproject.task.extractor.requests.get` or `myproject.task.extractor.get`, depending on whether your code-under-test uses `requests.get` or `get` to refer to the function. You test code doesn't even need to import `requests`

Comment: So it should be @patch("myproject.task.extractor.requests.get")?

Comment: Yes, your mocking is not correct. Your test code mocks the get_contacts function, which is not called at all in your code under test (the get_paged_contacts function). Rather, you should mock `myproject.task.extractor.requests.request`. By the way, the variable `has_more` is initialized once and never changed later, so you could end up in an infinite loop (this is not related to the original issue though).

Comment: I was so torn, but would a better option be ```while has_more is not False```? Thank you for all of the guidance!!

Answer (score 0):

After checking the edited question, here is a possible approach. The code under test could be the following:

```
def get_paged_contacts(endpoint: str,
                       query_string: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any], 
                       df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Return the results of the get request.

    Loops over api response and appends the results of a while loop 
    for pagination, then merges the results with the previously 
    extracted dataframe.
    """
    url = endpoint
    contacts = []
    response = requests.request("GET", url,
                                headers=header,
                                params=query_string).json()
    has_more = response["has-more"]
    offset = response["vid-offset"]

    # Get the contacts coming from the first response
    contacts.extend(response['contacts'])

    while has_more:
        querystring = {"limit": "100",
                       "archived": "false", "offset": offset}
        try:
            response = requests.request("GET", url,
                                        headers=header,
                                        params=querystring).json()

            # Update the looping condition in every response
            has_more = response["has-more"]
            contacts.extend(response['contacts'])
            time.sleep(10)
        except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError) as j:
            logger.error(f"Error occurred: {j}.")
            break

    contacts = pd.json_normalize(contacts)
    merged = pd.concat([df, contacts])
    # Reset the dataframe index after concatenating
    merged.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return merged
```

It can be refactored by having all requests inside the while loop, to avoid duplication, but it is not clear how you want to handle the query_string parameter, so I left it as it is. Then, the test code could be something like this:

```
@patch('my_project.task.extractor.requests.request')
def test_get_paged_contacts(request_mock):
    request_mock.return_value.json.side_effect = [
        PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
        PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
        PAGED_CONTACT_RECORD,
        CONTACT_RECORD,
    ]
    expected_df = pd.DataFrame(EXPECTED_CONTACT_RECORD)
    input_df = pd.DataFrame()
    res = get_paged_contacts('dummy_endpoint', None, input_df)
    assert request_mock.call_count == 4
    assert_frame_equal(res, expected_df)
```

The assert_frame_equal function is a utility provided by pandas to check two dataframes for equality. It is particularly useful for unit testing with pandas dataframes. You can check it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html). Of course, you need to import it with `from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal`

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful! I am getting 2 assertion errors: dataframe shape mismatch and an assert 2==4 for the call count...

Comment: The first one means that the result dataframe you are getting (res) is not the same as the expected one (expected_df). You can try to print the dataframes to see how they differ. The second error means that the request_mock is called 2 times instead of 4, so you need to change the side_effects so that the has_more is True in the first three records and False in the last one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and guidance! I was able to get detailed error messages from my pytest and realized that the dataframes were really different, so I refactoring my utils.py and now it runs perfectly. Thank you!!